# Laravel 6-Bootstrap Why Popover doesn't work while there is no error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popover, laravel-6

I am currently learning laravel via developing applications. 
I did quite a thing in backend but still having tough times when I encounter a front-end problem. I am using bootstrap scaffolding and want to create a form in 'popover'. I can do that later, now I just want to work this button out . I use the popover which is shown in bootstrap site. [Popover Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/)
I'm just putting a button in the page and want it to have a popover when clicked.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-container="body"
                        data-toggle="popover" data-placement="left"
                        data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
                        Popover on left
```

When I use the {{ asset('js/app.js') }} (I mean the local file in public/js/) I can't make it work. But when I use these cdn scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

and also add this script the bottom of body when I use cdn:

```
$(function () { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()})
```

It works. But this can't be a solution I would like to continue using my inner files not the ones imported from cdn. According to my readings and observations, in app.js these scripts/functions are already included. Only showing the path of app.js as stated above in blade file, should be enough in that case. (I run 'npm install popper.js --save' also). I would like to have a way to work this button out with internal js files.

Extra: When I type 'Popper' on console it responds me the following code line. So as I understand, it is defined.

```
Popper(reference, popper) {
var _this = this;
var options = arguments.length > 2 && arguments[2] !== undefined ? arguments[2] : {};
classCallCheck(this, Popper);
this.scheduleUpdate…
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Edit a year later:** I continue web development and when I saw this topic in my history I got wonder and read. I can imagine the problem when I see the issue and the reason that it didn't work back then is jquery needs to be imported or required before both popper.js and bootstrap. I should've understood that after inserting CDNs tho(by just looking the order). Text below belongs to a year ago and doesn't have any meaningful explanation.

Okay problem is solved in a very interesting way that I don't understand. Please share your comments if you have idea still. I deleted all cdn scripts, added `window.Jquery = require('jquery');` to resources/js/bootstrap.js file & kept `$(function () { $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()})` script under . Than I run `npm run dev`, after that it worked. It made no sense to me because there is a codeline in same file which includes jquery as I understand:
`try{ window.Popper = require('popper.js').default; window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery'); require('bootstrap');}..`
After this I deleted the line which I added at the start `window.Jquery = require('jquery');` and run `npm run dev` again, and it is still working. Now there is two things that I can think of: first; Once I added `window.Jquery = require('jquery');` and started `npm run dev`did something to one of my files and erasing that line doesn't matter now, or nothing special happenning here I just did something reaaaly wrong before opennig this topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;` in your `resources/js/bootstrap.js` or in `resources/js/app.js` file?

Maybe you could post the code from your bootstrap and app js files?

Comment: I am really sorry for responding this much late.

in resources/js/bootstrap.js 
`try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}`

public/js/app.js:
`window.Popper = __webpack_require__("./node_modules/popper.js/dist/esm/popper.js")["default"];
  __webpack_provided_window_dot_$ = __webpack_provided_window_dot_jQuery = __webpack_require__( "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js");

  __webpack_require__("./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js");`